# TimeSpan.Parse days element ranging from 0 to 10675199. Why this number?

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

From the Documentation for the TimeSpan.Parse method we see that the days element ranges from 0 to 10675199. I was just wondering whether there was any logic behind Microsoft choosing this number?

[TimeSpan.Parse Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from here: [TimeSpan.MaxValue Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The value of this field is equivalent to Int64.MaxValue ticks. The
>   string representation of this value is positive
>   10675199.02:48:05.4775807, or slightly more than 10,675,199 days.

Comment: and Int64 is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 because it is the largest number that can be made with a 64 bits. Thank you for enlightening me